# A->B->C relationship management in a 2 column sqlite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, window-functions, recursive-query

Hello Everyone and thank you in advance for the help.

I have setup a correspondance table that looks like this

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| A | D |
| C | D |

Of course this is a log of correspondance between one state to another at multiple points in time.
I am trying to transform this data into a "usable format" by flattening out the relationships between old and new to get to something like this:

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| A | D |
| B | D |
| C | D |

Does anyone have any idea how to do something like this in SQL?
Please keep in mind the iterations can run 7 levels deep.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT old, new, 1 level FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.old, t.new, level + 1
  FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
  ON c.new = t.old
)
SELECT DISTINCT old, 
       FIRST_VALUE(new) OVER (PARTITION BY old ORDER BY level DESC) new 
FROM cte
ORDER BY old;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=58491a2a755c9de357e547848a5dcf3f).